# Why is my 74HC04 not inverting my input?

Tags: digital-logic, debugging, not-gate

### My Situation

I have this:
https://www.tinkercad.com/things/gUv4whDvcO3-fabulous-crift/editel?tenant=circuits
Or if that fails: [image: My Circuit]
Schema (*I think this is right, I have not used schemas much before as I have only recently started my journey into electronics (Well, a couple of months ago, but I started with the basics then*)):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9nZqP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### My Question

When the first dip switch is off, the output of the hex inverter is high - correct
When the first dip switch is on, the output of the hex inverter is also high - ???
Where have I gone wrong? I have checked with the multi-meter and the input is 5V or 0V, however it always gives my 4.64V of output power, regardless of the input. This means that my LED is always on! *I have no clue on what is wrong here...*

Thanks for the help

Comment: This is why proper EEs choose to use schematics and not cartoons. Then you would easily see the problem. Draw a schematic.

Comment: Your drawing makes no sense. You have a pull up on inverter input and the DIP switch does nothing, so inverter output should be low and the LED should be always OFF. Please verify your built circuit matches the drawing.

Comment: I think it should make more sense now.

Comment: I was trying to follow this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sknUQoo6SMQ

Comment: I have added the schema, however if there is anything wrong, please let me know

Comment: Your schematic is incorrect and does not represent your breadboard layout. When SW2 is open the input to NOT1 is left floating. R1 serves no purpose. See Figure 2 in my answer.

Comment: Read the voltage on pin 1 with the switch open and closed. If that's switching then check on pin 2 with the LED out of circuit. Fault-find logically through the circuit.

Comment: In the version of the layout I am seeing now, both VCC and GND of the chip are connected to 5V (bottom most row adjacent to the red line) ?. The black line from bottom right pin of the chip should have gone to the second row in the board adjacent to the long black horizontal line.

Comment: @AJN, Fixed! :D

Comment: However it still doesn't work... :(

Comment: Shift the resistor to switch 1 instead of switch 4 ?

Comment: @Linux4Life531 the tinkercad link leads me to a 404 error page.

Comment: @AJN, You are AMAZING. It worked!!! You can add a new answer regarding that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The original circuit.*

The other side of the switch needs to be connected to ground (0 V).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSdKfs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Without a ground connection on the switch the input is always pulled high by the resistor.*

These sort of problems can be spotted much more easily on a schematic than on a wiring diagram or "cartoon" as the schematic shows the "schema" of the circuit.

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed that, but it still doesn't seem to be working. I am in the process of drawing out the schema

Comment: Thanks for adding the original circuit for clarification for future users, I should have included that in mine. Sorry!

Comment: You have accepted my answer, thank you. Did it work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Transistor. I have accepted your answer as it was helpful and it got the closest to solving the solution so far. I am still having difficulties. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Don't accept an answer until the problem is solved or until you've waited long enough that you think you won't get a better answer. Once you've accepted you discourage further answers. Thanks.

Comment: I was just following what was said when you hover over the accept answer button, which states "... or was the most helpful in finding your solution"

Answer (score 1):

In the original figure, the GND terminal is connected to the positive supply. It needs to be connected to ground. (Apart from the suggestions from other posters).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!!!

Comment: You can upvote the other answers also since those corrections are part of the full answer. @Linux4Life531

Comment: I have, however I only have 13 rep so they don't appear... :(